# OS X HD as USB HD (to PC)

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac

Is it possible to hook up a Mac to a PC via USB, and have direct access to the hard drive?

Is there any software that could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of, it will use Firewire instead of USB and doesn't work with the latest models of some Apple products as they do not have a Firewire port. Assuming you have a Firewire capable Mac and a PC with Firewire, you need to do two things:

1) Boot the Mac into [target disk mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Target_Disk_Mode). This is done by holding "T" while the Mac is booting. This will present the Mac as a Firewire drive to whatever it is plugged in to.

2) Install [Macdrive](http://shop.mediafour.com/ProductCart/pc/MainIndex.asp). This is an HFS+ (Mac filesystem) driver for Windows. Windows cannot natively read an HFS+ Volume. (There may be free alternatives, but I am not aware of them, I will continue to look and update accordingly.)

Comment: thanks, I'll have to get the right firewire cable to do this :)